# Upgrading from 12.04 LTS to 13.04

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

I am thinking of installing 12.04 LTS on a partition on my hard drive. 
When 13.04 matures will it be possible to upgrade to 13.04 from within 12.04 without dragging out the DVD, wiping 12.04 and doing a fresh install?

Answer (score 1):

You can install 13.04 through update manager. In software sources make sure that it is set to notify you of any new versions, otherwise it will only notify you of LTS versions. Then run update manager and it will tell you there is a new version available. Please note that you will have to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 then upgrade to 13.04.